# Reference for "$\mathrm{PFA}$ implies $L(\mathbb{R}) \cap \bigcup_{1 \leq k < \omega} \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ is productive"

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing, descriptive-set-theory

The preprint of the recent result of Aspero and Schindler, "Martin's Maximum$^{++}$ implies Woodin's Axiom $(*)$", mentions productive pointclasses, and states that "$\mathrm{PFA}$ implies $L(\mathbb{R}) \cap \bigcup_{1 \leq k < \omega} \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ is productive" is a corollary of Steel's paper "$\mathrm{PFA}$ implies $\mathrm{AD}^{L(\mathbb{R})}$", via "standard inner model theoretic arguments". For ease of reference I give the definition of a productive pointclass below.

A pointclass $\Gamma \subset \bigcup_{1 \leq k < \omega} \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ is said to be *productive* iff

1. $\Gamma \subset \Gamma^{\infty}$, where $\Gamma^{\infty}$ is the pointclass consisting of all universally Baire sets of reals,
2. $\Gamma$ is closed under complements, i.e. for all $k < \omega$, if $D \in \Gamma \cap \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^{k+1})$, then $\mathbb{R}^{k+1} \setminus D \in \Gamma$,
3. $\Gamma$ is closed under projections, i.e. for all $k < \omega$, if $D \in \Gamma \cap \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^{k+2})$, then
   \begin{equation*}
       \exists^{\mathbb{R}} D := \{\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{k+1} : \exists y \ (\vec{x}^{\frown}(y) \in D)\} \in \Gamma,
   \end{equation*}
   and
4. the closure of $\Gamma$ under projections is preserved by set forcing notions in a strong way: for all $k < \omega$, if $D \in \Gamma \cap \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^{k+2})$, then
   \begin{equation*}
       (\exists^{\mathbb{R}} D)^* = \{\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{k+1} : \exists y \ (\vec{x}^{\frown}(y) \in D^*)\}
   \end{equation*}
   in all generic extensions of $V$.

Now, I am curious about the following:

- Where did this notion of productive pointclasses first come about?
- Is there a more straightforward way to cite the result "$\mathrm{PFA}$ implies $L(\mathbb{R}) \cap \bigcup_{1 \leq k < \omega} \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^k)$ is productive"?

Any references with regards to these two questions are very much appreciated.

Comment: You can find a different proof of the productiveness of the required point-class here: arxiv2101.07573 Thm. 3.5.  It follows from the existence of class many Woodin cardinals and it amounts to say that second order number theory enriched with predicates for universally baire sets is invariant under set sized forcings